# AppleScript to move the mouse and click over specific element in Photoshop

Tags: applescript, mouseover, photoshop

I need a little bit of help with my script. Actually i am not sure if the problem is in the script at all or my concept is wrong.
So, what i am trying to achieve is to automate mouse clicks over two specific positions ( contract and then expand specific tab ) in Photoshop CS6/Cloud..and then return the mouse to the original positions.

[image: Contract]
[image: Extend]

I am using MouseTools and the script works fine when it's not applied in Photoshop but on the Desktop for example.
The actual problem is that no mouse clicks are executed in Photoshop for some reason. Actually from time to time they are but very rarely. There is no problem with mouse positioning..just with the clicks.
Here is what i wrote so far :

```
set mouseToolsPath to (path to home folder as text) & "UnixBins:MouseTools"
set {x, y} to paragraphs of (do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -location")
-- saves the original coordinates in two variables
set z to x
set zz to y

tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS6"
    activate
    delay 1
    
    set x to 1838
    set y to 463
    do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -x " & (x as text) & " -y " & (y as text) & " -leftClick"
    
    set x to 1799
    set y to 463
    
    do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -x " & (x as text) & " -y " & (y as text) & " -leftClick"
    
    set x to z
    set y to zz
    -- returns the mouse in original position
    do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -x " & (x as text) & " -y " & (y as text)
end tell
```

I have the feeling that i am trying to trick MouseTools that i am on a Desktop and it's getting bugged or something.

I've already solved this problem with Keyboard Maestro trial version and it works fine .. but since i can't afford to purchase a macro program especially for this problem .. i would like to write a script..and ofc gain some experience myself. :)

EDIT:
For the sake of finalising this post .. the temporary solution to this problem for me was a combination of "MouseTools" and "Cliclick". It works in 9 of 10 times and for some reason only when i run the code via executable made by "Script Editor". "Automator" runs in properly only when started from inside the GUI of Automator. Automator executable does not run in properly..for some reason. Really strange and buggy behaviour and probably will fail me in time..but still kind of does it's job for now.

```
set mouseToolsPath to (path to home folder as text) & "UnixBins:MouseTools"
set {x, y} to paragraphs of (do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -location")

tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS6"
    activate
    delay 1
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick c:1838,463"
    
    delay 0.5
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick c:1660,463"
end tell
delay 0.5
do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -x " & (x as text) & " -y " & (y as text)
```

Comment: Maybe try `pyauogui`... https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/

Comment: If you search Stack Overflow and Apple Stack Exchange, you should easily be able to find lots of answers to this problem.  They come up all the time and I've contributed three or four, which would likely apply to your situation.  You're right to consider the way you're approaching this: it sounds like it would break easily if the windows were in different positions.

Comment: Run this line of AppleScript by itself: `tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 whose bundle identifier = id of application "Adobe Photoshop CS6") to tell windows to return [it, action "AXPress"] of ui elements`.  If you get a result that's meaningful, then that's a much better way than your present method.  You can also use that same command and stick onto the end of it ` of ui elements` and run it again.  That goes one level deeper.  Stick another one on the end, etc. etc.  But, if I recall, isn't Adobe Photoshop scriptable?  Have you checked its scripting dictionary ?

Comment: @CJK Unfortunately i am not very experienced in any programing languange .. and some topics looks like a science fiction to me. I guess my approach should be more UI based in order to make the script works as it should..and as you said..not break by repositioning the buttons. Unfortunately this is how deep my knowledge goes. I will dive deep again in Stack Overflow and Apple Stack Exchange in order to get a clue how to solve this. Thank you !

Comment: @CJK When i execute the script you've told me .. the result is `{{}, {}}` and a pop-up error message appears `The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “System Events got an error: MouseClicker is not allowed assistive access.”` The Script is called "MouseClicker" and i give it permission in System Preferences/Security&Privacy to make changes.

Comment: @OutOfTouch Sorry for the delay in replying––I'm stealing seconds between minutes these days. It sounds like you dealt with the error appropriately, by giving `MouseClicker` assistive access. Did you run the code again ? As a piece of advice to bear in mind, any sort of debugging one does is best done in an environment that contains the *smallest possible* portion of the app's environment that will permit part of the app to be tested whilst excluding everything else that one believes ought not to be necessary. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ If the isolated part fails debug, it can be fixed; if it passes, then the error lies in the remaining parts of the app environment (which you add-in piece-by-piece until you get it). Anyway, the reason I said _"run this line of AppleScript by itself"_ was with a view to doing so in isolation, which I know can't possibly be obvious if this isn't your playground, so I apologise for not being clearer. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ The System Events error––though we believe dealt with appropriately––isn't worth speculating on, so I'd recommend running that line in a new _Script Editor_ document. If it returns `{{}, {}}`, then that's discouraging.  If it doesn't, then you have a potentially viable and more confident means of getting what you want done, and we can handle permissions etc. at that point, which are actually annoyingly fussy in an `.app` versus a plain script or an Automator workflow (it's a security thing).

Comment: @CJK Yeah..this "isolation" principle is what i am usually doing when looking for errors. It's ok.. i understand you. Unfortunately the result when running `"System Events" to tell (process 1 whose bundle identifier = id of application "Adobe Photoshop CS6") to tell windows to return [it, action "AXPress"] of ui elements` in new Script Editor is still the same : `{{}, {}}` What other options do i have ? The solution in my EDIT of the first post after a few days of testing is not kind of working as good as i thought.

Comment: No, those sorts of methods (where one automates clicks and keyboard presses) are not even worth contemplating.  They are fragile as they depend too much upon positions of elements and timing of events, which are too unpredictable; and they are not a pleasant user experience, as one cannot use the computer until the script finishes, and in the meantime, the screen becomes overactive and jarring to watch. The `{{}, {}}` result from the code I gave you tells us that Photoshop doesn’t expose any accessibility hooks to allow control over its UI directly. _Cont’d..._

Comment: _…Cont’d_ I should have checked this at the start, but have you combed through Photoshop’s AppleScript dictionary? If I remember, it is a scriptable app. It _might_ have a way to...  Actually, what **are** you trying to do ?  Are you wanting to close those panels ? To check if Photoshop is scriptable: `tell app "Finder" to get has scripting terminology of application file id (id of my app "Adobe Photoshop CS6")`.  If that returns `true`, then you can search through the application package for an `.sdef` file, which you can upload to a pastebin if you’d like me to look through it.

Comment: @CJK It returns TRUE. Unfortunately i can't find any .sdef file in my PS Application folder or in Library. It just finds NSObject and NSScript files where `.sdef` is mantioned. What i am trying to do is as simple as it is..just to contract and extend a specific tab in Photoshop CS6 and CC. Unfortunately this is the only solution to solve a visual bug caused by a PS extension that i use every day. The tab i have to contract and extend is the one of the extension. "Photoshop’s AppleScript dictionary" is something that i see for a first time. Looks interesting, complicated but worth testing.